# What's the typical schedule for the New Year's Eve party in Times Square

Tags: new-york-city, public-holidays

What's the typical schedule for the New Year's Eve party in Times Square?

I've checked out the [official website](http://www.timessquarenyc.org/events/new-years-eve/nye-schedule/index.aspx), but the schedule is really simple...I expected most animation and attractions, like concerts.

As far as I know last year Lady Gaga played a concert there. Is there a way to know who will sing this year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should search for press releases like [this one from November 9th](http://www.abcmedianet.com/Web/dnr/dispDNR.aspx?id=110912_07) or just look through [Dick Clark's website](http://dickclark.com/) for more details.